# Multiple declaration error in g++ (cygwin)

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin

I recently decided to start writing standards-compliant C++ instead of using Turbo-C++ and so I downloaded cygwin on windows 7 and installed g++. I tried to run a hello world program:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and typed this in cygwin:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
g++ test
```

Hoping I'd done alright, I pressed enter to find my heart broken by this giant wall of incomprehensible text:

```
$ g++ test.exe
test.exe: In function `mainCRTStartup':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.27-2/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:23: multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../lib/crt0.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.27-2/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:23: first defined here
test.exe: In function `mainCRTStartup':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.27-2/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:23: multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../lib/crt0.o:/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.27-2/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:23: first defined here
test.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x60): multiple definition of `__gcc_register_frame'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x10): first defined here
test.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0xc0): multiple definition of `__gcc_deregister_frame'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x70): first defined here
test.exe:crt0.c:(.text+0x50): multiple definition of `.weak._Jv_RegisterClasses.__gcc_register_frame'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
test.exe:cygming-crtend.c:(.idata+0x178): multiple definition of `__imp__ZSt4cout'
test.exe:cygming-crtend.c:(.idata+0x178): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `_Jv_RegisterClasses'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x35): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_Jv_RegisterClasses'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/crtbegin.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could somebody please take a look at this and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why `g++ test.exe`? Don't you just want to execute it with `./test`?

Comment: I don't promise that this will fix it, but try doing the compile to `test.o` instead of `test`, and then linking with `g++ test.o` instead of `g++ test`.

Comment: It would be better if you didn't name your program test.  Call it something like ctest or cpptest.  test is a command on unix.  If you just type test instead of ./test, it won't output anything and you will be running around in circles for ages trying to figure out why your program is not printing anything.

Comment: What does g++ do when given an already compiled and linked executable?

Comment: @FredLarson I feel like an idiot now.

Comment: @JamesKanze That does seem to be the error in my ways. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for the   `g++ test` command

the command `g++ test.cpp -o test` will compile and link your code. you can run it using `./test.exe`